# Dymola modelica defining inputs for frequency analysis

Tags: modelica, frequency-analysis, dymola

Inputs in my multibody model are  road unevennes as function of distance the model is working fine for time simulation but when I linearize the system, then i get  error saying no inputs or outputs defined.As In the picture:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8AmxzbhEQ_FczFuaDNhQjlqVUE/view?usp=sharing

I defined combitable as a input and parameter then I get the error:
Translation of TRyViertalMbsa:
Component type specifier CombiTimeTable is a block, this cannot be combined with the prefix input .
Component declared as CombiTimeTable combiTimeTable in Modelica.Blocks.Sources
Conflicting causality for combiTimeTable (input ) and its element y(output )

How can I define inputs and outputs for the state spac system?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you are asking Dymola to linearize the model **including the boundary values** (the input time series). What you really want is to linearize the model only and let Dymola perturbate the inputs in order to determine the linear model. See example model:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8ojPn4YxnI9a1FFa0ozY2tlT1U/view?usp=sharing

So, you must replace the two CombiTimeTable with two input connectors (`Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput`). 
Also, you would probably want to add one or more output connectors (`Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput`) via mechanical sensors - angle, position or whatever.

**Operating points**

If you want to linearize your model around a specific operating point different from zero, you should add these (constant) values to the inputs and subtract them from your outputs. I don't know if there is a smarter way to handle the operating points in Dymola's linearization function.

Best regards
Rene Just Nielsen

Comment: Thank you very much!  I defined outputs with the sensor applying this way but when I give combi time table as an input it still does not recognize the table as an input when I want to have the bode plot of the system. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8AmxzbhEQ_FUFB2c2JFemx1X0k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yusuf, if you just delete the two `CombiTimeTables`, Dymola can perform the linearization. The `CombiTimeTables` contain time series of input data (boundary conditions) which are _not_ required to linearize your model. You can always re-apply them to your linearized model afterwards if you want to compare the **time responses** of the linear and nonlinear models. Also, there are a number of methods to compute the **frequency response** of the linearized system but for that purpose you won't need the `CombiTimeTables`.